# Will output change if right_index is used instead of left_index with both left_on and right_on defined in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## I have two dataframes

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7'],
                'B': ['B1', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'],
                'C': ['A1', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7'],
                'D': ['B1', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7']},index=[4, 5, 6, 7])
```

## Output I

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_index=True, left_on='A', right_on='A')
```

## Output II

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', right_index=True, left_on='A', right_on='A')
```

Why do these above two outputs differ? Basically I want clarification regarding the functionality of `right_index` and `left_index`?

Comment: I would expect the opposite behaviour so to me it's a bit ambiguous, could be a bug as my understanding is that the `left_index` values should end up in the merged result for output 1 and the opposite for output 2 but we see the opposite

Comment: I think this is a bug , the left_index seems to be buggy, the right_index gives expected output.

Comment: My understanding is that `left_index` and `right_index` are to be used in lieu of `left_on` and `right_on`. It appears you are overriding the `_index` argument with the `_on` argument.

Comment: It's a bug to allow both sets of parameters. [Filed on GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16228).